# distribute list to buckets by window or cycle for processing

Tags: sql-server, math

In SQL Server I have a source list of id's that I want to re-order in a specific way for processing. My original table has a list of ids like 10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,30,40,40,50,50,60 and a unique key associated with each one. They can be in any order. I want to distribute them to buckets by window or cycle so that they won't conflict. I'm familiar with the aggregate functions, I'm having trouble with the math to get it distributed. I could do it with a loop but for performance reasons I would like to do it in a single query if possible.

I have a query to get a count and priority like

```
Count   Id  Priority
5       10  1
4       20  2
2       40  3
2       50  4
1       30  5
1       60  6
```

The # of buckets is arbitrary although decided ahead of time. If it was 3 I want id's 10,20,40 in the first cycle then 10,20,50 in the second cycle. If the bucket was 4 then 10,20,40,50 in first and 10,20,40,50 again in second.

Another way for me to express the problem is I want to grab the first x from the new table by count, decrement the count and then grab the next x until exhausted.

Took the solution suggested and re-wrote it but I'm still looking for a single sql query solution if possible.

I've updated the suggested loop a bit which should be a little more optimized haven't yet updated it to my real workload

```
declare @bucket int, @b int, @maxrows int  
declare @buckets table (fstrEntityHash varchar(100), bucket int)
declare @count table (flngCount int, fstrEntityHash varchar(100))
declare @bucketTemp table (fstrEntityHash varchar(100), bucket int)

select @bucket = 3, @maxrows = 20

insert into @count
select  COUNT(1) as flngCount, 
    fstrEntityHash
from tblTest
group by fstrEntityHash
order by COUNT(1) desc

set @b = 1
while (1 = 1)
begin
insert into @bucketTemp
select top (@bucket) fstrEntityHash, @b
from @count
where   flngCount > 0
order by flngCount desc;

if @@rowcount = 0
   break

 update C
 set    C.flngCount -= 1
 from   @count C, @bucketTemp I
 where  C.fstrEntityHash = I.fstrEntityHash

insert into @buckets
select  * 
from        @bucketTemp

if (select count(1) from @buckets) >= @maxrows
   break

 select @b = @b + 1
 delete from @bucketTemp

end

select * from @buckets
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if it's possible with CTE, cause there are some restrictions (you cannot use `top` in the recursive part and cannot use aggregates in the recursive part).
So for the moment I got this semi cycle:

**UPDATE**:

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9ce3/42)

I've changed a query a little bit, so it will not count all over the table all the times. I also deleting from table `@counts` all unnecessary records and calculate minimum priority with which I can get records.

```
declare @bucket int, @b int, @Priority int
declare @buckets table (Id int, bucket int)
declare @bucketsTemp table (Id int primary key, [Count] int, Priority int)
declare @counts table (Id int primary key, [Count] int, Priority int)

select @bucket = 3, @b = 1
select @Priority = min(Priority) from temp

while (1 = 1)
begin
   insert into @bucketsTemp (Id, [Count], Priority)
   select top (@bucket)
       t.Id,
       isnull(c.[Count], t.[Count]) - 1 as [Count],
       t.Priority
   from temp as t
       left outer join @counts as c on c.Id = t.Id
   where t.Priority >= @Priority and isnull(c.[Count], t.[Count]) > 0
   order by t.Priority

   if @@rowcount = 0
       break

   insert into @buckets
   select b.Id, @b
   from @bucketsTemp as b

   update @counts set
       c.[Count] = b.[Count]
   from @counts as c
       inner join @bucketsTemp as b on b.Id = c.Id

   insert into @counts
   select b.Id, b.[Count], b.Priority
   from @bucketsTemp as b
   where b.Id not in (select c.Id from @counts as c)

   delete @counts
   from @counts as c
   where
       c.[Count] = 0 and
       not exists (select * from @counts as t where t.Priority < c.Priority and t.[Count] <> 0)

   delete from @bucketsTemp

   select @Priority = min(Priority) from @counts
   select @b = @b + 1
end

select * from @buckets
```

---

First try was

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9ce3/23)

```
declare @bucket int, @b int   
declare @buckets table (Id int, bucket int)

select @bucket = 3, @b = 1

while (1 = 1)
begin
  insert into @buckets
  select top (@bucket)
     t.Id,
     @b
  from <your table> as t
     left outer join 
     (
         select t.Id, count(*) as [Count]
         from @buckets as t
         group by t.Id
     ) as B on B.Id = t.Id
  where t.[Count] - isnull(B.[Count], 0) > 0
  order by t.Priority asc

  if @@rowcount = 0
     break

  select @b = @b + 1
end

select * from @buckets
```

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping for a single query solution because in my original I have millions or id's. I'll try it out and see though.

Comment: For millions you need to optimize solution a bit. I'll edit my post later, Ihave a pair of ideas but have no time right now

Comment: I've updated the query a bit which should be a little more optimized haven't yes updated it to my real workload

Comment: I've added another query. It should work faster than first one. It's possible to create a formula for nth backet by calculating and then write a query, but I doubt that such a query will be faster than iterating, because you'll need to read through the table for all buckets.